# Powershell Function Output collection

Tags: powershell

I have functions and each function returns an return code. 
I want to output the following:

```html
function ReturnCode
-------- ----------
 wrapkey         255
 mapkey          233
 delkey            0
```

I tried:

```
$Outarray = @()

$Outarray += $_.SetProperty("WrapKey") | select "WrapKey", ReturnCode 
$Outarray += $_.SetProperty("MapKey") | select "MapKey", ReturnCode

$Outarray | Format-Table
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for calculated properties, the syntax of which is as follows:

```
@{Name='Name of resulting property';Expression={<# actual value calculation goes here#>}}
```

So for the result you want (one object per `SetProperty()` call), that would be something like:

```
$_.SetProperty('WrapKey') | Select-Object @{Name='Function';Expression={'WrapKey'}},@{Name='ReturnCode';Expression={$_}}
```

And then repeat for `MapKey` and `DelKey`. Since only the property names vary, you can throw them into a loop:

```
$OutputCodes = foreach($Name in 'WrapKey','MapKey','DelKey'){
    $_ | Select-Object @{Name='Function';Expression={$Name}},@{Name='ReturnCode';Expression={$_.SetProperty($Name)}}
}
```